# dd backup all data, included deleted and unused blocks?

Tags: backup, recovery, dd

I have an old hard drive with a lot of family photos I want, but some of them were probably deleted at some point. I don't want to lose any data on that disk, so I could recover it later, so how would I go about using dd piped into gzip? Does dd back up all data, including unused sectors with deleted data on it by default, and in a completely recoverable state like on the hard drive itself? (I used a recovery program and it found some deleted photos, would running it from the dd backup but mounted work the same and give the same results??
Would this work just fine for this? 'sudo bash -c "dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip > /home/user/oldhddbackup.gz"' Thank you!